# DB table name for agent properties

Tags: urbancode

What is the table name in uDeploy DB to get the agent properties.
I am looking for agent host name property for each agent installed in uDeploy.
Agent.hostname or Agent.HOSTNAME.

Answer (score 0):

The Agent Properties are stored inside the Udeploy Database in the table "vc_persistent_record" . However, this field is a CLOB and contains the hostname nested inside XML tags and cannot be used directly.

The other option to get the agent hostname just by passing an agent name is by using the UDeploy CLI on your Windows Command prompt. This is the command to do that:

```
udclient -username *myusername* -password *mypassword* -weburl *https://udeploy.com/*  getAgentProperty  -agent *myagentname* -name HOSTNAME
```

Output of abovecommand:
`YOURSERVERHOSTNAME`

References to get this going: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4GSP_6.2.4/com.ibm.udeploy.reference.doc/topics/cli_install.html

https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Environment_Variables.html